# Is it possible to add header ini ajax post cross domain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

i try to add header for authorization in ajax post to external domain. The code looks like this

```
$.ajax({
        url: "externalUrl",
        headers : {
           "Authorization": token
        },
        type: "POST",
        data: (data),
        crossDomain : true,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result){
            //run something here                   
         }
});
```

i've set the CORS setting in my server too

```
res.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
res.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Method", "*")
res.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
```

but when client try to post ,the method change into OPTIONS
Is it possible to add header ini ajax post cross domain?

Comment: it should send the post request after the options request if the server responds with allow headers

Comment: it response with code 200 but there is no data result @madalinivascu, i try to debug in my post handler but there are no sign that the request is hitting the handler.

Comment: has the option request the allow header you provided?

Comment: i've added handler for option, additional headers can be read. but i found that ajax hit 3 times in my server, it hit post handler, then option handler, then post handler, is it supposed to be like that? @madalinivascu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved by adding handler for options and add allow header in that handler as suggestion from madalin ivascu. it's possible!